# Adding things into a MongoDB document using PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

Using MongoDB, I have a `history` collection, with multiple documents in it. When initiatied, they look like this :

```
{'_id': ObjectId('58a71211545fc61fd8b2f420'),
 'category': 'blue',
 'last_update': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 14, 0, 1),
 'timeline': [
    {
    'score': 0,
    'when': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 14, 0, 1)
    }
 ]
}

{'_id': ObjectId('58a71211545fc61fd8b2f421'),
 'category': 'red',
 'last_update': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 14, 0, 1),
 'timeline': [
    {
    'score': 0,
    'when': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 14,  0, 1)
    }
 ]
}
```

Using PyMongo, I would like a query that adds things into a document (for instance, for the document with `{'category' : 'blue'}`), in the `timeline` element, like that :

```
{'_id': ObjectId('58a71211545fc61fd8b2f420'),
 'category': 'blue',
 'timeline': [
    {
    'score': 0,
    'when': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 14, 0, 1)
    },
    {
    'score': 10,
    'when': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 14, 0, 2)
    },
    {
    'score': 20,
    'when': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 14, 0, 3)
    }
 ]
}
```

The only thing I found out (with `collection.update_one()`) erases the previous content :

```
{'_id': ObjectId('58a71211545fc61fd8b2f420'),
 'category': 'blue',
 'timeline': [
    {
    'score': 10,
    'when': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 14, 0, 2)
    },
    {
    'score': 20,
    'when': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 14, 0, 3)
    }
 ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you are using `update_one` ?

Comment: `db.my_collection.update_one({'category': 'blue'},{'$set': {'timeline' : [{ 
    'score' : 30, 'when': datetime.datetime.now()
}]}}`

Comment: Can you try $push instead of $set ? Push operator for array and Set for field.

Comment: Like that ? `db.data_graph_dev.update_one({'category': 'blue'},
                             
                             {'$set': {'timeline' : {'$push' : [{ 
                                 'score' : 30, 'temps': datetime.datetime.now()
                              }]}}})` => `I get this error : WriteError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$push' in 'timeline.$push' is not valid for storage.`

Comment: No just replace the $set operator with $push. Rest stays the  same. Something like `db.my_collection.update_one({'category': 'blue'},{'$push': {'timeline' : [{      'score' : 30, 'when': datetime.datetime.now() }]}}`

Comment: Alright, at last, it works (without the `[ ]`) ! `db.data_graph_dev.update_one({'category': 'blue'},
                             
                             {'$push': {'timeline' : { 'score' : 30, 'temps': datetime.datetime.now()
                              }}})` Thank you very much, put it in answer if you want rep points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the update operator $push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

```
db.my_collection.update_one({'category': 'blue'}, {
    '$push': {'timeline': {'score': 30, 'when': datetime.datetime.now()}}}
```